# Как перевести "can't be bothered with"

Tags: перевод, значения

Как известно, can't be bothered может переводиться как *лениться что-либо делать*, либо *не иметь желания*, либо *наплевать (She probably can't be bothered)* и т. д.

В песне Burn It Down группы Daughter [есть](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/daughter/burnitdown.html) строки:

> Now the world is only white noise
>   Frequencies that I can't understand
>   **I can't be bothered with the teachers
>
>   Always trying to shape the way I act**.

Мне интересно: как лучше или даже как правильно перевести выделенные строки?
*Мне наплевать***(?)** *на учителей* (или, если посмотреть на контекст, *умников*)*, вечно лезущих в мою жизнь*?

В моем переводе мне «не нравится» то, что, возможно, верным переводом будет не «наплевать», а что-нибудь другое, о чем я не знаю и о чем не пишут доступные мне словари.

Comment: Мне фиолетово на учителей...?

Comment: "По барабану" еще.

Comment: @SergeySlepov и *по фиг* туда же тогда :) То есть там не что иное, как *наплевать, фиолетово*? Просто чем-то меня смущают эти строки — и не могу точно сказать чем.

Comment: I believe "I can't be bothered with" means "I'm sick of", "I've had enough of" here.

Comment: @Quassnoi interesting. Are there any other contexts where *can’t be bothered* means “be sick of” etc.?

Comment: @shabunc простите, мне не понятно, почему вопрос закрыт. Создавая его, я следовал всем указаниям в справке насчет переводов. Не могли бы вы пояснить, *что* такое, по-вашему, «prior research effort» и как я могу обозначить ее в своем вопросе?

Comment: @aer: sure, http://www.pregnancyforum.co.uk/pregnancy-chat/214654-family-cant-bothered-them.html http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2050719 http://www.dubaimemes.com/meme/1572-when-you-just-cant-be-bothered-with-the-morning-traffic-anymore It's not the mainstream usage, but it's used in this sense every now and then

Comment: @Quassnoi oh, thanks! By the way, can you explain why my question is on hold? (I asked shabunc above.)

Comment: @aer: he would know better but I believe that's because your question is, in fact ,"what does this English poem really mean?" You are providing decent Russian translations to what you thought was the meaning of the English phrase right in your original post.

Comment: @Quassnoi ok. This closing grieved me so much. It doesn’t really matter (because I’ve already got an answer) but I hope shabunc will find time for explanation all the same.

Comment: @Aer prior research effort означает что вы попытались получить ответ на этот вопрос самостоятельно, пришли к некоторому количеству вариантов (указаны) но по тем или иным причинам (указаны) считаете, что ваши варианты не годны и или не точны. 

Возможно, нам стоит как-то действительно более подробно объяснять в пояснительном тексте, что именно считается оффтопом.

Comment: @shabunc так а почему, если у меня всё указано, вопрос закрыт?

Comment: у вас не указано - это если prior research effort есть указано - например, у вас не указано, почему вам не нравится ваш собственный ответ. Так же если вы не согласны с принятым по вашему вопросу решением (ну или просто вам нужно больше информации по этому поводу) можно задать вопрос на  meta.russian.stackexchange.com

Comment: @shabunc о боже, какой ужас! Хорошо, я добавлю, чем же мне «не нравится мой собственный ответ». Надеюсь, тогда мой вопрос будет переоткрыт? And it isn’t really understandable what you are talking about “prior research effort” in Russian. So, let’s try speaking English: do I have “prior research effort” in my question?

Comment: @Aer нет не будет. No, it won't. I strongly suggest you to post a question at meta if you still insist this should be clarified.

Comment: can't be bothered  mainly uk informal
​
If you can't be bothered doing/to do something, you are too lazy or tired to do it: надоели или устал

Comment: @nicolas-chabanovsky  - here's  reasoning behind decision made - https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-has-my-question-been-closed

Comment: @Quassnoi this looks like an edge case to me - I've been just waiting if there will be enough reopen votes - that may indicate that I'm actually wrong. This has not happened. In such cases I'm wholeheartedly relying on my fellow moderators. If you think it's an on-topic in it's current form - let's reopen.

Comment: "и я устала от советов, когда и как себя вести."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если ознакомиться с полным текстом, то похоже, что лирическую героиню всё настолько беспокоит (информационный хаос, советчики норовят учить, приятель покинул и т. д.), что ей хочется сжечь всё вокруг, начав с собственного дома. По этому смыслы вроде "меня не пронять учителям" вряд ли отсюда.

> Мир только белым шумом мучит,
>
> В его частотах - непонятки.
>
> *Достало, что все вечно учат,*
>
> В каких вести себя мне рамках.
>
> ...................
>
> (Гори же всё, гори огнём - к чертям собачьим!)

Answer (score 2):

"Не колышат" - близко по смыслу и по образности
upd:
can't be bothered несет смысл (urbandictionary: When you really aren't in the mood to do something, generally because you are tired, feeling lazy or it's not important)
Возможные переводы по смыслу:
не до того 
недосуг
нет желания заниматься

Исходное предложение содержит элипсис
I can't be bothered with (paying attention to) the teachers
Always trying to shape the way I act.

Перевод "не колышат" сохраняет неформальный стиль и передает отношение к учителям и к их поучениям

Comment: It would be really helpful if you explain your choice a bit. Could you please add to the answer why do you think it's the best translation in this context? What is the general idea if we look at the whole lyrics?

Answer (score 2):

> Теперь мир для меня просто шум,
>   Бессмысленные частоты.
>   Мне безразличны те, кто поучают,
>   Всегда стараясь указать, как мне себя вести.

I've added "для меня" ("for me") that isn't in the original, but is silently implied and sounds better by meaning and by rhythm. The version without it would be:

Теперь мир - просто шум

I've also omitted "white", as "white noise" is more of a technical term in Russian with little to no meaning for a kid. If a close literal translation is desired, then:

Теперь мир - просто белый шум

that I can't understand - means "make no sense to me", "meaningless", therefore "Бессмысленные"

I can't be bothered - the meaning here is "I don't care", "they mean nothing to me", thus best translating as "Мне безразличны"

with the teachers - "teachers" here are not "instructors", but rather those with an unsolicited advice or guidance. The proper verb here is not "учить", but "поучать".

Always trying - this is straight forward "Всегда стараясь"

to shape - here means "to project their way", essentially like "to tell" or "to show", except not as a suggestion, but rather a demand, although not as strong as "to make". The best equivalent here is "to show" that, as a suggestion, is "показать", which is not applicable here, but, as a demand or forceful influence, is "указать".

the way I act - straight forward "как мне себя вести"  that fits nicely by the meaning, feeling and rhythm.

This translation retains the meaning and even emphasizes that the "noise" is the instructions of the unsolicited teachers, that is the substantial connection and transition from the first and the second parts. It is also very literally close and has the proper rhythm making it sound as poetry, but not just word-by-word translation.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the song, a possible translation of `he cannot be bothered with teachers` appears to be

> Ему `нет дела до` учителей

or even

> `Учителя ему пофиг` (жарг.)

In comparison, for the phrase `he cannot be bothered with such minutiae` suitable translations will be:

> Он не будет заморачиваться такими деталями (жарг.)
>
> Он не будет утруждать себя такими деталями
>
> Он не будет обременять себя такими деталями

Answer (score -1):

Несмотря на наличие "литературных" переводов данных строк, хотелось бы отметить, что в них слегка изменён оттенок выражения слов оригинальной песни.

- "лениться" - не хотеть что-либо делать, при этом подразумевается что на это нет весомой причины
- "не иметь желания" - не хотеть что-либо делать, при этом подразумевается, что на это может быть причина (например, плохое настроение)
- "наплевать" - быть безразличным к чему-либо (осознанно или нет), выражение имеет негативный оттенок и не рекомендуется использовать, например, в литературных текстах
- "не колышат" - совершенно обратное слову "bothered" - не беспокоит, безразлично (синоним "наплевать"). Так же не рекомендуется использовать в литературных текстах и интеллектуальных диалогах.
- "достало" - (= "надоело"), имеет слегка агрессивный оттенок, не выражает депрессии или печали. Разговорное выражение, не рекомендуется использовать в литературных текстах.

В тексте песни, скорее, говорится о том, что её "беспокоят" (original - bother), то есть отвлекают не важными для неё вещами, которыми она не хотела бы заниматься (в данный момент), и\или которые вызывают у неё грусть\печаль.

"I can't be bothered" - дословно "я не могу беспокоиться\переживать". Говорится о том, что она не хочет быть обеспокоенной\переживать. То есть, она понимает, что сейчас её беспокоят, но не хочет, чтобы это продолжалось; она устала от этого. Подобные фразы обычно не используются в устной речи, но используются во внутреннем диалоге с самим собой.

"teachers always trying to shape the way I act" - дословно "учителя, которые всегда пытаются указывать мне, как вести себя".

Комбинируя две основные части предложения с использованием "with" получаем, что исполнительница ведёт диалог с собой - "Я не хочу больше беспокоиться\переживать из-за учителей, которые всегда пытаются указывать мне, как вести себя". То есть она хочет жить своей жизнью и принимать решения самостоятельно. Данные выражения подразумевают глубокие душевные переживания, глубокую печаль, депрессию.

Резюмируя,
"can't be bothered with” = "не могу переживать из-за"